# Heroku Node.js error code H10 "App crashed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment, crash

I just started learning NodeJS and tryied to deploy it to heroku. When I try using 'heroku open' this log happened.

```js
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778660+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778661+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778661+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778662+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778662+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2020-10-08T14:19:52.778663+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-08T14:19:52.810513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-08T14:19:52.811098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-10-08T14:19:52.828543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart: `node index`
2020-10-08T14:19:52.828751+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-10-08T14:19:52.829002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-08T14:19:52.829206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart script.
2020-10-08T14:19:52.829406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-08T14:19:52.847042+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T14:19:52.847382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-08T14:19:52.847546+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-08T14_19_52_830Z-debug.log
2020-10-08T14:19:52.945200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-08T14:19:52.999786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-08T15:48:09.000458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-08T15:48:11.710414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-08T15:48:14.879546+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:14.879557+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart /app
2020-10-08T15:48:14.879558+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index
2020-10-08T15:48:14.879558+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028554+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028556+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028556+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028557+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028557+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'nodemon'
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028557+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028558+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028559+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028559+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028560+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028560+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028561+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:15:17)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028561+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028562+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028562+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028562+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028563+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028563+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028564+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2020-10-08T15:48:15.028564+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-08T15:48:15.045283+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-08T15:48:15.045797+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-10-08T15:48:15.055020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart: `node index`
2020-10-08T15:48:15.055328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-10-08T15:48:15.055591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-08T15:48:15.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart script.
2020-10-08T15:48:15.056088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-08T15:48:15.066474+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-08T15:48:15.066992+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-08T15:48:15.067250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-08T15_48_15_057Z-debug.log
2020-10-08T15:48:15.168797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-08T15:48:15.225575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-08T15:48:15.228118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-08T15:48:18.092770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-08T15:48:22.002464+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.002544+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart /app
2020-10-08T15:48:22.002550+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index
2020-10-08T15:48:22.002551+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164769+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164771+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164771+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164772+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164772+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'nodemon'
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164772+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164773+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164794+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164795+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164801+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164801+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164801+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:15:17)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164802+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164802+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164802+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164803+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164812+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164823+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164823+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2020-10-08T15:48:22.164824+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-08T15:48:22.214230+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-08T15:48:22.214698+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-10-08T15:48:22.224614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart: `node index`
2020-10-08T15:48:22.224863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-10-08T15:48:22.225157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-08T15:48:22.225473+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs_crashcourse@1.0.0 prestart script.
2020-10-08T15:48:22.225688+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-08T15:48:22.236263+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.236699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-08T15:48:22.236908+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-08T15_48_22_226Z-debug.log
2020-10-08T15:48:22.378922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-08T15:48:22.443106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-08T15:48:23.480249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=11b5f46a-aeb7-4a22-aa83-87d815a763ba fwd="114.124.170.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-08T15:48:24.761780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=41ce56e1-5274-47ef-80a7-bf712b681836 fwd="114.124.170.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-08T15:55:05.602396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=c04fbdb5-e9ac-48fd-bc76-48b125727fd2 fwd="114.124.178.60" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-08T15:55:06.230385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=87220f0f-1ae0-4f91-82f4-832bebfc59f0 fwd="114.124.178.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-08T15:56:44.427873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=cf47f697-a1ca-49d5-81c6-7bebeb363739 fwd="114.124.178.60" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-08T15:56:44.988746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nameless-anchorage-18480.herokuapp.com request_id=3c72b009-f912-4de6-9e5c-800a8936386d fwd="114.124.178.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I searched online for solutions and have tried these solutions:

- heroku restart
- use process.env.PORT
- npm clean cache
- checked that I am in master branch
- added engine with correct version
- Use "scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
  }

None of these seems to work. Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "nodejs_crashcourse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.3",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  },
  "description": "Node Crash Course",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "dev": "nodemon index"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nodejs_crashcourse.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "crashcourse"
  ],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

and here is my index.js:

```js
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const nodemon = require("nodemon");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // Build file path
  let filePath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    "public",
    req.url === "/" ? "index.html" : req.url
  );

  // Get extension of the file
  let extname = path.extname(filePath);

  // Initial content type
  let contentType = "text/html";

  // Check ext and set content type
  switch (extname) {
    case ".js":
      contentType = "text/javascript";
      break;
    case ".css":
      contentType = "text/css";
      break;
    case ".json":
      contentType = "application/json";
      break;
    case ".png":
      contentType = "image/png";
      break;
    case ".jpg":
      contentType = "image/jpg";
      break;
  }

  // Read file
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      // Page not found error
      if (err.code == "ENOENT") {
        fs.readFile(
          path.join(__dirname, "public", "404.html"),
          (err, content) => {
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            res.end(content, "utf8");
          }
        );
      } else {
        // Other server error
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end(`Server Error: ${err.code}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Success
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType });
      res.end(content, "utf8");
    }
  });
});

//Check if environment variable exists and if not set 5000 as default
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the `const nodemon = require("nodemon");` line. Just delete it.

Comment: Wow didnt expect that to be the solution. It worked fine when I use 'npm start' or 'npm run dev', why does it bug out on heroku?

Comment: I think Heroku ignores dev dependencies so when it comes across that line it crashes because it can't find that package.